# Two sample t-test vs one sample t-test (use mean of another dataset)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

If I compare two dataset for difference using t-test. I am aware that I should use two sample t-test. However, what if I take the mean of one dataset and use one sample t-test instead?

From what I can see, it is conceptually valid in terms of the usage scenario of one sample t-test. However, I guess this is wrong (and this conversion yields different significance result).

I am a bit confused with this. Can someone share some insight? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "conceptually valid"?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could,  but your result would be imprecise since the mean you obtain from dataset 1 is not the real mean of the population, but rather an estimation.

You would also have to justify why you choose the mean of one of the datasets as a "true mean (whatever that refers to)" and you don't do the same with the other.

Anyway, for big enough samples there should not be too much of a difference, but I don't see any reason to avoid doing things properly! When working with Statistics, we already have to make a ton of "controversial" assumptions, so why make one more?

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis you're testing is about equality of two *population means*.

By replacing one population mean with a sample mean, you would treat as a known constant the random variable representing the mean of one of the samples, and would thereby substantially underestimate the variance of the difference.

As a result, you would inflate the significance level from the nominal one.

A quick example simulation in R suggests that for equal sample sizes and a nominal 5% significance level your true significance level (i.e. your actual type I error rate) is in the ballpark of 15-16% across a range of typical sample sizes between 20 and 200 -- triple what we  wanted it to be. It seems to be more than 5 times the desired level for a 1% test.

(We could compute the values these simulations estimate but it doesn't seem essential to discover their exact values)

To my astonishment, I have seen this same error made surprisingly frequently, even a few times by researchers.

---

```
 n=20;rowMeans(replicate(10000;{x=rnorm(n);y=rnorm(n);c(t.test(x,y,var.equal=TRUE)$p.value,t.test(x,mu=mean(y))$p.value)})<.05)
```

(with only 10000 simulations I suggest running it multiple times to get a good sense of what the averages are -- or to increase the simulation size)

Comment: Actually this is what I am confused about. I guess it is almost impossible to get population mean unless every individual is measured. the typical one sample z-test is usually performed with sample mean, but real population mean, right?